# Is there a ContextMenu plugin in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, contextmenu

jQuery UI have released menu widget in version 1.9, but this menu widget does not have support for context menu, is there any Context-Menu plugin in jQuery UI?

Answer (score 2):

So far there is no official Context-Menu plugin or widget in jQuery-UI, so we([VectorWorkz](http://www.vectorworkz.com/)) have created Context-Menu plugin based on [jQuery-UI Menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/) widget. Take a look at this [JQFAQ topic](http://jqfaq.com/jquery-ui-context-menu-plugin/), there we have discussed about this Context-Menu plugin.